# byte concatenation in a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Let's say I have the following chain:

```
bchain = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'
```

Then I create an iterator for this chain:

```
iterator = iter(bchain)
```

What I want to do is to have the first 4 bytes of bchain, but by using the iterator and exhaust it. And to do that in a lambda expression.

I have tried to do:

```
lambda iterator: b''.join(next(iterator) for i in range(4))
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buffer interface, int found
```

It seems like next(iterator) gives the int represented by the next byte in the chain, and not the byte itself. The lambda, in this case, should output

```
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03'
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want only the first 4 bytes?

Comment: You've way, way overcomplicated your problem. Do you want to know how to write this cleanly, or do you want to know why your existing code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs for [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) explains:

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers.

In other words, if `b = b'abcd'`, then `b[0]` or `next(iter(b))` is `97`, not `b'a'`.

If you want to construct a `bytes` object from an iterable of small integers, don't use `b''`, just call the constructor:

```
bytes(next(iterator) for i in range(4))
```

Of course a much simpler way to do what you wanted is to just slice the `bytes`:

```
bchain[:4]
```

Or, if you want to work on any iterable of small integers, not just a `bytes`, use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
bytes(itertools.islice(bchain, 4))
```

---

As J.F. Sebastian points out, this is the reason [PEP 467](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/#addition-of-optimised-iterator-methods-that-produce-bytes-objects) includes `iterbytes`. Assuming it's added to Python 3.5, you could use `b.iterbytes()`--or, if `b` is just "some `bytes`-like iterable", `memoryview(b).iterbytes()`--instead of `iter(b)`, and then you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: `bytes(next(iterator) for i in range(4))` did the works. Thank you. I've thought of slice but it doesn't increment the iterator itself for further manipulation.

Comment: @RobinCarlier: As I said in the answer "If you want it to work on any iterable…, use `islice`" That includes iterators.

Comment: [pep 467 (draft) proposes `bytes.iterbytes()` method](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/#addition-of-optimised-iterator-methods-that-produce-bytes-objects): `iterator = bchain.iterbytes()`